# Getting Z value on mesh for respective XY

Tags: three.js

I am trying to get the Z value on the mesh when i pass the X & Y coordinate. Sorry, i am new to three js.

I am using raycaster for the same. My plan is to set origin exactly above the point and direction just below it. So that it will intersect on mesh and will return me the respective values.

Here is my code:

```
 for(var i=0;(i)<points.length;i++){
    var pts = points[i];
    var top = new THREE.Vector3(pts.x , pts.y , 50 );
    var bottom = new THREE.Vector3( pts.x , pts.y , -50 );

   //start raycaster

   var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
   raycaster.set( top, bottom );

   // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
   var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.getObjectByName('MyObj_s').children, false);

if (intersects.length > 0){
    console.log(intersects[0].point);
 }
```

}

However the above code results shows totally different X & Y positions, and definitely inaccurate Z values.

> top
>
> Object { x: 58.26593421875712, y: 63.505675324244834, z: 50 }
>
> bottom
>
> Object { x: 58.26593421875712, y: 63.505675324244834, z: -50 }
>
> Result
>
> Object { x: -2.9414508017947445, y: -13.236528362050667, z:
>   -2.0969017881066634 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> raycaster.set( top, bottom );

It seems you are not using `Raycaster.set()` correctly. As you can see in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.set), the method expects an origin and a direction vector. In your code, you just pass in two points.

- The first parameter `origin` represents the origin vector where the ray casts from.
- The second parameter `direction` is a normalized (!) vector representing the direction of the ray.

`three.js R104`

Comment: How can i get the direction vector for the same?

Comment: Try it like so: `direction.subVectors( bottom, top ).normalize();`. `direction` is an instance of `Vector3`.

Comment: Yes, i got the normalized direction vector { x: 0, y: 0, z: -1 } but ray caster is still not returning the z value for the same ordinate.

Comment: Probably because your xy coordinates do not lie on the mesh.

Comment: I tried passing multiple points it returns correct value for the last one. I tried shuffling the points and it is only working for the last point. :/

Comment: It's best when you share your current work of progress as a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/. Otherwise it will be hard to provide more feedback.

Comment: Actually i am unable to provide demo as the code is too much with lots of libraries. However the modified version of it looks like this https://jsbin.com/vamumedato/edit?js

And the issue you can see in this picture:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VxlnPXBoDD7cpqItzJu4WGNEHkZohw0h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: TBH, I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve. The raycasting looks correct that's really all I can say.

Comment: No, it is returning the same value. Look on the console and with the JS. As direction is down facing however the result comes out to be inclined.